# Android - What is the best way to create different select (touch regions) on an image button/view

Tags: android, image, button, region

I would like to have different select regions on and image button that are not rectangular?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to compose multiple images together that look like one button but under the hood are actually separate buttons/images.